# The Magic Fairies of Object Serialization

Tags: java, file, object, serialization, time

```
System.out.println("Hello brave souls!");
```

I have a few questions about Object Serialization. I am working on a new version of my math game, and forgot to have it save the game mode on the last three sessions. The records are being saved via object serialization, which leads me here. What I want to know is:

1.) Does object serialization somehow keep hold of the time at which the objects were saved to the file?
2.) In changing ANY of the n objects in the file, do you have to load the one you want to change into memory (via cycling through the objects with a loop), change it, and then rewrite EVERY LAST FREAKING OBJECT back to the file? //seems tedious

Comment: I lol'ed, despite myself. You get a +1 just for that.

Comment: serialization is not the same as persistence. A database would be a better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.) Does object serialization somehow keep hold of the time at which the objects were saved to the file?

No. It saves the object and only the object, plus whatever it needs to reconstitute it, such as its class name.

> 2.) In changing ANY of the n objects in the file

You can't change any of the *N* objects in the file. You have to reconstitute the file as objects, change the object(s), and reserialize.

> // seems tedious

It is tedious. Nobody said it wouldn't be tedious. You are using it as a database. It isn't. It is a serialization, which also implies that it is a stream. Exactly the same applies to a text file.

Comment: Another observation/question about object serialization: I notice, when deserializing the .ser file with the records to be modified, modifying the records that need modified, and then serializing them in another .ser file, the newly-created .ser file is MUCH smaller than the old one EVEN THOUGH THERE IS THE SAME AMOUNT OF OBJECTS IN EACH FILE! There are 65 objects, and I was just modifying a boolean value on three of the objects. Can anyone explain why this might be happening? //and should I even worry about any data being erased

Comment: @MikeWarren You're probably running into the issue that `ObjectOutputStream.reset()` is the cure for. You may have written the original stream with resets after each object, and not written the updated stream the same way.

Comment: Given the nature of the program that I am trying to make, the old file has resets after each object. In fact, I made a class to extend ObjectOutputStream that calls reset() in writeStreamHeader(). But, I try to, as a test, copy this object serialization file object-by-object using something like:

    for (int x = 0; x < recordCounter.read(); 
    {
 //initialize record to be written
 record = (ArrayList<GameData>)olddata.readObject();
 newdata.writeObject(record); //and write it to the new file
    }

and the result is a disaster!

Comment: forgive me, as I have tried identifying my code by indenting it only four spaces and it didn't work.

Comment: I fixed it. The problem here was that I wasn't calling `newdata.reset();` when `x > 0`

Answer (score 3):

Serialization serializes an entire object graph. If you are saving a game, you will probably want to call ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(myGame), which will write the entire game object and all non-transient properties it references, recursively.

To change it, load the game into memory using an ObjectInputStream, change a value, and write it back out.

You might also want to chain a GZIPInputStream and GZIPOutputStream if you are dealing with large amounts of data, it can shrink serialized size a good bit.

If you are dealing with really large objects, an embedded database might be a better option, since you can change a single field without loading the whole thing into RAM.

Lastly, if you want to update the timestamp of an object when it's serialized, implement the writeObject method in the Serializable pseudo-interface. Update your timestamp, then call defaultWriteObject on the supplied ObjectOutputStream. This will give you 'last persisted' behavior.

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException
```

Comment: This problem is needing to be solved on the grounds that I have to modify some data to make sure that it counts in the right places. Also, I have plans to add a calendar feature. So, I am looking for a way to preserve the timestamp. I am thinking about doing something like declaring a file output stream, a file input stream, an object output stream, and an object input stream, setting the input streams to the stuff currently in the file, and then "dumping" the data into the file provided by the output stream. 

Would the timestamp be something you would explicitly have to save?

Comment: Probably create the timestamp when the object is instantiated (in the constructor), not when it is serialized.